# NoDogSplash not block wlan0 traffic TP-Link MR3020 OpenWrt

Tags: openwrt

I have trouble with configuration nodogsplash 0.9_beta9.9.6 on MR3020 OpenWRT 12.09.
Here my nodogsplash config file.
https://gist.github.com/anonymous/4b8834f375b073ca5a3a

My network config.
https://gist.github.com/anonymous/3e6a740b73d6b249dcec

My wireless config
https://gist.github.com/anonymous/d776daa618dfcdbe72f3

The problem is that my phone connect directly to the internet through the access point and doesn't open splash page.
When I look in LuCI traffic graph I see phones traffic, but in

ndsctl status

I see Current clients: 0.

Answer (score 0):

In your `config interface 'WiFI'` section you specified `ifname` as `eth0`, while most likely it should be `wlan0`.

Then, in `nodogsplash.conf` file, you should correctly set the `ExternalInterface` parameter (the one that you use to connect to the Internet, check ifconfig output for your external IP).